# How to define an Orthogonal Vector in a Horizontal Plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

Say we have a vector {f} that lies within a horizontal plane, and we want to define a second vector {s} that lies within the same horizontal plane, and it is orthogonal to the first vector {f}. Is there any method that I can use to define the second vector {s}?

I should mention that I do not have any idea of the components of {s}; However, I know that it should be in the same plane as {f} and be orthogonal to it. For better illustration, I have attached [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaD2B.jpg) of the problem.

Thank you in advance for any help that you might be able to provide.

Comment: What do you know about orthogonal vectors?

Comment: Your picture certainly is not good, as $f$ appears to be pointing well out of the plane. The question is: How are you given the plane and how are you given $f$? The strategy should be to pick any other vector $v$ in the plane and then use projections (dot products) to find the component of $v$ orthogonal to $f$.

Comment: Dear @saulspatz, I know that when two vectors are orthogonal, the dot product of them will be zero

Comment: You must realize that there is not a unique solution.  You can set one of the components arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously $s$ is not unique, since any scalar multiple of $s$ is also orthogonal. Let $s=(s_1,s_2)$ and $f=(f_1,f_2)$  Then orthogonality is defined by $f_1s_1+f_2s_2=0$, which gives the relationship between  $s_1$ and $s_2$.

Comment: Dear @herb, thank you for replying. Now that we have this relationship, how can I determine the components of {s}?

Comment: I switched $f$ and $s$ roles originally.  It has been corrected.  Knowing $f$ we can get the relationship between $s$ components.

Comment: I still do not know how {s} can be determined by using f1s1 + f2s2 = 0; if it is possible please share more details regarding the process of finding {s}. Thank you very much

Comment: Assume $|f_1|\lt |f_2|$ and let $s_2=-\frac{s_1f_1}{f_2}$ while setting $s_1$ to any value.

Answer (score 0):

Say your horizontal vector has components $(a,b,0)$. Then a horizontal vector perpendicular to it can be taken to be $(-b,a,0)$.

The general case $v$ in a plane $\pi$ with a normal direction $n$. Then a vector perpendicular to $v$ and in the same plane $\pi$ has to be perpendiculat to both $v$ and $n$. So we can take it to be $v \times n$.